# Display sequential post number / count (not id) instead of "posted on date" - Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I'm creating a "150 energy tips" website, and I would like to number each post with unique number but I just don't have the skills to do it.
Then, I would display numbers instead of date so if I have 150 posts published on the site I should see `tip n° x" (x=1,2,3,4...149,150)` on each.
It doesn't matter if the oldest published post is 1 or 150, random numbers are good as well.

Comment: Do you have some code you can share?

Comment: If you don't mind the numbers being random use the post ID. Without code we can't help you.